# Pass variable from form to next page and put in sql statment php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a dropdown (and or excel type look) that I need to pull data from the database. When I have an item selected I need to pass the info to the next page via a session. I have the drop down pulling from the database but I need to list Name and address in the dropdown.

If this is not possible I can do a list of items from a search but I will need to make the id a link to pass the id to the next page where I need to build a report.

If you can give me some info on this I would appreciate it.

Here is what I have for code on the dropdown

Code: Select all

```
<?php   
// declare database connection variables.
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "sample";
$tbl_name = "tbl_report";

// connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "SELECT id, name, address FROM $tbl_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$dropdown = "<form action='report.php' method='post'>"; 

$dropdown .= "<select name='items' class='select'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$dropdown .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . 
$row['name'] . ' - ' . $row['address'] . '</option>';;
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
$dropdown .= "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
$dropdown .= "</form>"; //closing the form tag
echo $dropdown;
?>
```

What I need to do is pass the ID to the next page and have the $id show up in the code for my next sql statement.

Here is the code that I have for the next page sql statement.

```
select * from $tbl_name where id = (this is where I get hung up on.)
```

What I need is a way to pass the $row['id'] to the next page and put that in the sql code and then use the get method to display the info on the form of that page.

Here is the setup of the pages.  select-report.php (this is where the drop down is) --> report.php.

Here is the form for report.php where i need to carry over the value of id and do a sql of select * from $tbl_name where id=[$post=items];  Then i need to use the $get to put all the items in the form below:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td width="20%">Water Purveyor
<input name="water-purveyor" type="text" id="water-purveyor" size="35" />
</td>
<td colspan="2">Facility Contact
<input type="text" name="facility-contact" id="facility-contact" /></td>
<td colspan="2">Facility Address
<input type="text" name="facility-address" id="facility-address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Manufacturer
<input type="text" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer" /></td>
<td width="20%">State
<select name="state" id="state">
</select></td>
<td width="20%">Model #
<input name="model-num" type="text" id="model-num" size="10" /></td>
<td width="20%">Serial #
<input name="serial-num" type="text" id="serial-num" size="10" /></td>
<td width="20%">Meter #
<input name="meter-num" type="text" id="meter-num" size="10" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Owner
<input type="text" name="owner" id="owner" /></td>
<td>Phone #
<input name="phone-num" type="text" id="phone-num" size="12" /></td>
<td>Caged
<input type="checkbox" name="caged" id="caged" /></td>
<td>Locked
<input type="checkbox" name="locked" id="locked" /></td>
<td>Code key
<input name="code-key" type="text" id="code-key" size="6" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Owner Address
<input name="owner-address" type="text" id="owner-address" size="50" /></td>
<td>Owner City
<input type="text" name="owner-city" id="owner-city" /></td>
<td>Owner State
<select name="owner-state" id="owner-state">
</select></td>
<td>Owner Zip
<input name="owner-zip" type="text" id="owner-zip" size="10" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact
<input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" /></td>
<td>Contact Phone
<input name="contact-phone" type="text" id="contact-phone" size="10" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Other</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Facility Name
<input name="facility-name" type="text" id="facility-name" size="40" /></td>
<td colspan="3">Assembly Address
<input name="assembly-address" type="text" id="assembly-address" size="75" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">Onsite Location
<input name="onsite-location" type="text" id="onsite-location" size="75" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">email Address
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="125" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SHUTOFF VALVES</td>
<td colspan="2"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td>N/A</td>
<td>Good</td>
<td>Poor</td>
<td>Fail</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Valve 1</td>
<td colspan="2"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="v1-na" id="v1-na" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="v1-good" id="v1-good" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="v1-poor" id="v1-poor" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="v1-fail" id="v1-fail" /></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Valve 2</td>
<td colspan="2"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="v2-na" id="v2-na" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="v2-good" id="v2-good" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="v2-poor" id="v2-poor" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="v2-fail" id="v2-fail" /></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Assembly Replacement?
<input type="checkbox" name="assembly-replacement" id="assembly-replacement" /></td>
<td>if yes Serial #
<input type="text" name="assembly-replacement-serial" id="assembly-replacement-serial" /></td>
<td>New Installation 
<input type="checkbox" name="new-install" id="new-install" /></td>
<td>Permit #
<input type="text" name="permit-num" id="permit-num" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Containment
<input type="checkbox" name="containment" id="containment" /></td>
<td>Isolation
<input type="checkbox" name="isolation" id="isolation" /></td>
<td colspan="2">Assembly Ground Clearance
<input type="text" name="assembly-ground-clearance" id="assembly-ground-clearance" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Domestic
<input type="checkbox" name="domestic" id="domestic" /></td>
<td>Irrigation
<input type="checkbox" name="irrigation" id="irrigation" /></td>
<td>Fire Line
<input type="checkbox" name="fire-line" id="fire-line" /></td>
<td>Alarmed Fire Line
<input type="checkbox" name="alarmed-fire-line" id="alarmed-fire-line" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><strong><em><u>Double Check Balve Assembly Repair</u></em></strong></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Repairs</td>
<td>Check Valve 1</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Check Valve 2</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
<td>Cleaned 
<input type="checkbox" name="cv1-repair-cleaned" id="cv1-repair-cleaned" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Cleaned
<input type="checkbox" name="cv2-repair-cleaned" id="cv2-repair-cleaned" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Replaced</strong></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><strong>Replaced</strong></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rubber Kit
<input type="checkbox" name="cv1-rubber-kit" id="cv1-rubber-kit" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Rubber Kit
<input type="checkbox" name="cv2-rubber-kit" id="cv2-rubber-kit" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Other 
<input type="checkbox" name="cv1-other" id="cv1-other" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Other
<input type="checkbox" name="cv2-other" id="cv2-other" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">Comments      
<textarea name="cv1-other-comments" id="cv1-other-comments" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
<td colspan="2">Comments
<textarea name="cv2-other-comments" id="cv2-other-comments" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Initial Test By      
<input name="initial-test-by" type="text" id="initial-test-by" size="50" /></td>
<td colspan="2">Certified Tester #
<input type="text" name="certified-tester-num" id="certified-tester-num" /></td>
<td>Test Date/Time
<input type="text" name="test-date-time" id="test-date-time" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pass      
<input type="checkbox" name="initial-test-pas" id="initial-test-pas" /></td>
<td>Fail
<input type="checkbox" name="initial-test-fail" id="initial-test-fail" /></td>
<td colspan="2">Calib Expire Date
<input type="text" name="calib-expire-date" id="calib-expire-date" /></td>
<td>Guage Serial #
<input type="text" name="gague-serial-num" id="gague-serial-num" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Repair Test By
<input name="repair-test-by" type="text" id="repair-test-by" size="50" /></td>
<td colspan="2">Repair Date/Time
<input type="text" name="repair-date-time" id="repair-date-time" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Final Test by
<input name="final-test-by" type="text" id="final-test-by" size="50" /></td>
<td colspan="2">Certified Tester #
<input type="text" name="ft-certified-tester-num" id="ft-certified-tester-num" /></td>
<td>Test Date/Time
<input type="text" name="ft-date-time" id="ft-date-time" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pass
<input type="checkbox" name="ft-pass" id="ft-pass" /></td>
<td>Fail
<input type="checkbox" name="ft-fail" id="ft-fail" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">Comments
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Video upload <input type="file" name="uploadvideo"  /></td>
<td colspan="2">Image 1 <input type="file" name="uploadimage"  /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">Image 2 <input type="file" name="uploadimage2"  /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">Image 3 <input type="file" name="uploadimage3"  /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">Image 4 <input type="file" name="uploadimage4"  /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">Image 5 <input type="file" name="uploadimage5"  /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove `method='post'`, if you want it to be `get` (or change `post` to `get`). Value should be accessible via `$_GET['items']`.

Comment: add `print_r($_POST)` before the query and check what is getting posted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery when to get the selected value like this

```
$("#dropdownid").change(function({  var vals = $(this).val(); })
```

then when you are redirecting to next page then add it as get parameter

Answer (score 0):

(report.php)

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
     $option = $_POST['items'];
     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE FIELD_NAME = '$options'");
}
```

Comment: SQL injectable. Also if using request for `submit` why not use if for setting the `option` value?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to next page using php session.

```
$_SESSION ['name'] = $value;
```

and you can get value using php session from next page.

```
$value = $_SESSION ['name'];
```

Comment: OP will also need to start the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
     $option = $_REQUEST['items'];
     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE FIELD_NAME = '$options'");
}
```